# how to iterate and filter over a xml tags and check the condition in dataweave function in mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

Input to Dataweave

```
  <root>
     <client>
       <name>abc<name>
       <status>success</status>
     </client>
     <client>
       <name>def<name>
       <status>success</status>
     </client>
     <client>
       <name>ghi<name>
       <status>success</status>
     </client>
     <client>
        <name>jkl<name>
        <status>failed</status>
     </client>
     <client>
        <name>mno<name>
        <status>success</status>
     </client>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
  <clients>
    <name>abc<name>
    <name>def<name>
    <name>ghi<name>
    ........
  </clients>
    <status>false</status>  // if all status are success then true otherwise false
 </root>
```

Here i can able to iterate over each xml tag and map the name value under clients tag using dataweave. But i have to map single output for all status .
i.e when all are success my status would be true , if any one status is failure my status would be false.
For this we have to write a function which will iterate over an each xml tag and have to return the output either trur or false based on the condition.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Filter the list of status which equals to "failed". If it returns no record, means all status are success then true. Otherwise (it returns more than one records) false.

```
status: (sizeOf (payload.root.*client.status filter $ == "failed")) == 0
```

Or

```
status: not (payload.root.*client.status contains "failed")
```